# Why does html's default open method be set to Visual Studio Code URL Handler in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: html, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Why does html's default open method be set to Visual Studio Code URL Handler in Ubuntu18.04? VSCode version 1.28.2. When I set the html default open mode to chromium, the default open mode of html becomes Visual Studio Code URL Handler after restart. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I just met the same problem. All explanations are in this pretty technical article [XDG MIME Applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#lsdesktopf).

To quickly solve it :

- open the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` with your preferred editor
- in the section `[Default applications]`, find the line starting with `text/html=`
  It probably is `text/html=code-url-handler.desktop`
- set it to `text/html=firefox.desktop`.
  Or `google-chrome.desktop` for Chrome
- save the file

To check your can run the command `xdg-mime query default text/html` to display the application used to open HTML files.

You can also simply use `xdg-open <path to some HTML file>` and verify that is opens in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Eren, 
when you selected chromium, did you go to "properties" or "open with" on the right click menu?
Sometimes my won't preference won't stick if I do it with "properties", but when I go to "open with" and actually open it one time, then it works for me permanently.